# find the word "year" in a cell and consider the number before the word

Tags: excel, vba, cell, extract, cpu-word

So I have a list of cell that contains year-term on it but they don't follow a specific order, which means "1 Year" could be at the beginning or "6 years" at the end. 
I used the VBA below to identify all cells that contains "Year","Years","Yr" and "Y" but not sure how can I extract the number that comes before, I believe I need to have Celloffset 0,2 (since there is a space between the number and term "year") but not sure how to set up the code to not only find the word but consider 2 position before and put in the column next to it.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated!

```
Sub Sample()
Dim MyAr(1 To 3) As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range, bCell As Range
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

MyAr(1) = "year"
MyAr(2) = "years"
MyAr(3) = "Y"

With ws
    '~~> Loop through the array
    For i = LBound(MyAr) To UBound(MyAr)
        Set aCell = .Columns(1).Find(What:=MyAr(i), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bCell = aCell
            aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3

            Do
                Set aCell = .Columns(1).FindNext(After:=aCell)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                    If aCell.Address = bCell.Address Then Exit Do
                    aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You could consider using the `Split` function if you know it's always going to be separated by a space. Something like `Split(aCell.Value, " ")(1)` to access the first part

Comment: Alternatively, if you're just looking to extract the value within the string, you can use the Left function in combination with InStr to search for the space

Comment: If the numbers are preceeding the term year then you can simply use the `Val` function. It will evaluate the string parameter until the first non numeric char, and will not drop any error whatever follows. So Val("1Year"), Val("1   Year"), Val(1/12year") all return 1. Yet the above `Split` option is good, too.

Comment: It also appears that you're searching specifically for year, so you might want to consider using wildcards `*` that allow it to be part of a larger string or set `.MatchWholeWord = false`